# Highcharts render issue on Android 14 and Chrome 121

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts, mobile-chrome

We have a very strange and serious problem with highcharts
The chart renders but upon any movements like scrolling up and down the page or touching the chart to see the tooltips, it kind of jumps around like it lags or something. See the gif below:

[image]

### Live demo with steps to reproduce:

This is generated on Highcharts demos page as well as ANY website that has highcharts like the website bellow
If you have android 14 and chrome 121 you can use that to go to highcharts demos or the website bellow and see for yourself.

- https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/line-chart
- https://app.pulsegrow.com/chart-sharing/fRsBJ

### Affected browser(s):

- This bug is only generated on Android 14 AND Chrome 121
- Android 13 with Chrome 121 works fine.
- Android 14 with Chrome 120 works fine.
- Firefox, Vivaldi, Opera work fine.

It's the ***combination*** of Android 14 + Chromium Engine 121 that generates this strange issue.

### Notes

I'm using highcharts 11.3.0
BUT I also tried to downgrade highcharts but issue is still generated on every highcharts version down to version 8. So the version of highcharts doesn't matter.

I hope somebody can help because this is very important to us.

Comment: I've logged your issue on our GitHub page for reference: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20556. If we can reproduce it, we'll continue the discussion in that thread.